# Shiny app: Read .csv files according to drop-down menu selection

Tags: r, csv, shiny, shiny-reactivity, shinyapps

I want to develop a Shiny app visualising a set of data.

The data is available as a collection of CSV files, as downloaded from European Environmental Agency (see
https://www.eea.europa.eu/themes/air). The file Stations.csv contains information about each station.
There is one CSV file for each station and each pollutant (PM2.5, PM10, SO2 and NO2) measured at the station (not every pollutant is measured at every station). The filenames are of the form EoICode_PollutantCode.csv. Each row of these files contains hourly measurements of that pollutant at that station.

There are over 300 .csv files I need to work with, so I was wondering if it is possible to read the desired .csv files depending on user's selection from a drop-down menu in the ui. In other words, the user would select the desired polutant e.g. SO2, then the app would read all .csv files with name pattern '*_SO2.csv'. 
Or even better, to also filter the potential .csv file-to-read depending on the station as well. 
e.g. From the first drop-down menu the user selects the polutant S02, then from a second drop down menu the user selects a Station e.g. Prague (or a number of stations), then submits selections through a submit button and the app reads 'Prague_SO2.csv', then plots graphs etc.

Any ideas? As I am feeling lost there

Answer (score 0):

For this answer, you will need to work on your `datasets` object.

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

# datasets <- list.files("~/Downloads/Wine_example/", pattern=".*.csv$")

datasets <- list(
  `red_wine` = read.csv("~/Downloads/Wine_example/winequality-red.csv"),
  `white_wine` = read.csv("~/Downloads/Wine_example/winequality-white.csv")
)


ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput("data", "Pick a wine dataset:", choices = names(datasets)),
  dataTableOutput("table")
  )

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$table <- renderDataTable({
    req(input$data)
    datasets[[input$data]]
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thanks for that! I'll definitely try out this approach.